# How to get access to a Spotify public playlist

Tags: spotify

I am working on a slack bot that at some point needs to have access to a public playlist on Spotify, but no private info and it doesn't need to modify the playlist. The app has no web component so can't use user authentication. I can get access tokens using the client_credentials grant-type, since the playlist is eligible to public without logging in. However I get the 'This request requires user authentication' error. I have access to the userID and playlistID. I already read 
1. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/
2. https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-playlists-tracks/

I was just wondering if anyone else had a similar problem / how they solved it.

Thanks

Comment: just in case: are you sending the access token on your header as required?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking maybe the access token I acquired doesn't grant access to public playlists?

Comment: You can access any playlist, regardless of it being private or public, as long as you have an access token, the owner's userId, and the playlistId. Could you please double check that you're using the GET HTTP method in your request?

Comment: Ok got it working, might have been using POST before, not sure. Thank you!